# Position Fixed inside tab content in angular material2 is positioning with respect to tabs and not window

Tags: css, angular-material2

So I'm using angular material2 for creating tabs. Inside any tab content when I create a div element with position fixed that positions itself with respect to the scope of Tab content `as if that's the entire window`.

If I keep decreasing the top the div gets disappeared inside the tabs. By inspecting I can see the element, but no matter how high z-index I give that won't show up above the surface of tabs.

```
 <md-tab label="Device Groups" style="min-width: 100px">


        <div style="position: fixed;top:-5%;left:40%;min-width: 20%;min-height: 30px;z-index:100000000000;background: red">

          </div>
</md-tab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens because angular material adds transform property. Did this to fix:

```
.mat-tab-body-content, .ng-trigger, .ng-trigger-translateTab, .mat-tab-list{
      transform: none !important;
   }

   .mat-tab-body-wrapper{
    overflow: inherit !important;
   }
```